# Why is the JVM's default timezone different in these cases

Tags: java, date, datetime, jvm, timezone

Turkey decided recently (September 6, 2016 ) to permanently stay in Daylight Saving Time (DST). This act canceled the ending of DST previously scheduled for October 30, 2016, 04:00:00. Clocks were not changed.

Turkey is between +2 and +3 utc, so now it will stay in +3. Here you can see

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/turkey/ankara?year=2016

*Information above is taken from this link of which problem is similar with mine. ([Java timezone in turkey (rejected daylight saving)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400793/java-timezone-in-turkey-rejected-daylight-saving))

Until today, manufacturers have provided some solutions about it. For example, Windows configured a timezone - (UTC+03:00) Istanbul - for Turkey. However, some problems about the same topic still continues like mine.

I develop Java web application that uses jdk1.8.0_101. I make it run over Apache Tomcat 7.0. In this application sometimes I use date objects. **But, when I get date object (new Date()), I see that default timezone of JVM is different from the timezone of OS(Windows but different versions) that the application runs over.**

I test it on three different environment. I use same java code and same jdk version in each environment. Java code is;

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println(zone.getDisplayName());
System.out.println(zone.getID());
```

**TEST CASE-1)** **My laptop - Windows 10 Pro (Administrator user) - new Date() object returns *Wed Dec 21 10:00:38 EET 2016* Test Code Result:**

```
Eastern European Time
Asia/Istanbul
```

[image]

==================================

**TEST CASE-2)** **My Dektop PC - Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (Restricted user on the company network) - new Date object returns *Wed Dec 21 10:00:38 EET 2016* Test Code Result:**

```
Eastern European Time
Asia/Istanbul
```

[image]

==================================

**TEST CASE-3)** **Virtual Server - Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Administrator user) - new Date object returns *Wed Dec 21 11:03:11 GMT+03:00 2016* Test Code Result:**

```
GMT+03:00
GMT+03:00
```

[image]

==================================

**** In 3rd test case, virtual server returns right date information, but in others, they return wrong date. I know that I can set timezone while getting date object. However, the project is big and it means a lot of date object that I have to correct it. Also, 3rd test case shows us that the problem can be solved by configuring the system date/time. What can I do about it? I wait for your recommendations.

Comment: "But, when I get date object (new Date()), timezone of the object is different from timezone of operating system(Windows)" `Date` doesn't actually have a time zone. The only sense in which it uses a timezone is that `Date.toString()` uses the JVM's default timezone; so your question might be simplified to "why is the JVM's default timezone different in these cases".

Comment: @AndyTurner I am editing the question based on your recommendation!

Comment: Please include the output of `System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault())` in all cases.

Comment: @AndyTurner I've added what u wanted.

Comment: Does [anything here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly) help you?

Comment: @AndyTurner It helps a lot, Andy. Thank u so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest changes related "Turkey switched from EET/EEST (+02/+03) to permanent +03" has not been integrated in JDK8 update 101 which you are using, infact it is not part of latest JDK 8 update 112. You need to manually upgrade the tzupgrader tool to get the changes in your JDK.
Here is the "tzdata2016g" version that has the "Turkey switched from EET/EEST (+02/+03) to permanent +03" integrated, you can find more details here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html
You need to manually install tzupdator tool that you can get from here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html
I hope that solves your problem.