# Hybris drop down for time zone

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

is there a way whereby I can use the time zones provided by ZoneId class provided by java.time?I want the the different time zones to reflect as a drop down in Hybris Management Console.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to editing java timezone list? Details are here about time zone editor tool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40401351/2847159